# How to use gridsearch to find best learning rate in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

how can I use gridsearch to find the best learning rate for the gradientDescent?

```
def computeCost(X,y,theta,theta0):
#TODO
m = len(y)
J = 0
s = 0
#Iterative Solution
for i in range(0,m):
    s = s + ((theta0 + np.dot(theta,X[i])) - y[i])**2
J = s/(2*m)
return J

def gradientDescent(X,y,theta,theta0,alpha,iterations):
#TODO
J_history = np.zeros((iterations,1))
m = len(y)
Y = y.reshape(m,1)
for iter in range(0,iterations):
    s1 = 0
    s0 = 0
    for i in range(0,m):
        s1 += ((theta0 + np.dot(theta,X[i])) - y[i])*X[i]
        s0 += ((theta0 + np.dot(theta,X[i])) - y[i])
    theta0 = theta0 - alpha*s0/m
    theta = theta - alpha*s1/m
    J_history[iter] = computeCost(X,y,theta,theta0)
return theta, J_history
```

Dataset : https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV()*  to tune the learning rate. It is possible to define your estimator function(gradientDescent), parameters, and scoring function. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html for more information.